# ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\crud\views\employee\addOrEdit.ejs:8

Tags: node.js, ejs, node-modules

hi m trying to edit data in nodejs using ejs as a view engine but it says: ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\crud\views\employee\addOrEdit.ejs:8, how to solve it,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

by clicking the given link below I go onto edit page:

```
  <a href="/employee/<%= this.id %>" class="btn btn-outline-warning my-2 my-sm-0">Edit</a>
```

at edit page I get this:

```
    ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\crud\views\employee\addOrEdit.ejs:8
      6|       </h1>

      7|       <form action="/employee" method="POST">

   >> 8|         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= employee.id %>">

      9|         <div class="form-group">

      10|           <label for="name">Fullname</label>

      11|           <input


  employee is not defined
      at eval (eval at compile 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:633:12), <anonymous>:11:26)
  at returnedFn (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:668:17)
  at tryHandleCache (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:36)
  at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
  at View.render (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
  at tryRender 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
  at Function.render 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
  at ServerResponse.render 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
  at ServerResponse.res.render (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express-ejs-layouts\lib\express-layouts.js:77:18)
  at router.get (D:\nodejs\crud\controllers\employeeController.js:7:6)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  at next (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
  at Route.dispatch 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
  at Layer.handle [as handle_request] 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
  at D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
  at Function.process_params 
  (D:\nodejs\crud\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
```

addOrEdit.ejs:

```
   <form action="/employee" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= employee.id %>">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Fullname</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="name"
        name="fullname"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Full Name"
        value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined' ? name : '' %>"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email</label>
      <input
        type="email"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Enter Email"
        value="<%= typeof email != 'undefined' ? email : '' %>"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Mobile</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id=""
        name="mobile"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Mobile"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password2">City</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="password2"
        name="city"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="City"
        value=""
      />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
      Submit
    </button>
    <br>
    <a href="/employee/list" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-info my-2 my-sm-0">view all</a>
  </form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\crud\views\employee\list.ejs:21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602722/referenceerror-d-nodejs-crud-views-employee-list-ejs21)

Comment: that's another thing which includes changing in function code but here only link problem

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue, It seems like ```employee``` data is not being sent as ```res.render("addOrEdit", {employee: docs});```

Comment: it sent but nor working:   router.get('/:id',(req, res) => {
 Employee.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
  if (!err) {
   res.render("employee/addOrEdit", {
    employees: doc
   });
  }
 });
});

Comment: in cmd it is showing that error is in this line <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= employees.id %>">

Comment: Can you share the error that is being printed ? @dev

Comment: ReferenceError: D:\nodejs\crud\views\employee\addOrEdit.ejs:8
    6|       </h1>
    7|       <form action="/employee" method="POST">
 >> 8|         <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<%= employees.id %>">
    9|         <div class="form-group">
    10|           <label for="name">Fullname</label>
    11|           <input

employees is not defined

Comment: Is it employee or employees, I'm confused in your question above you have used ```<%= employee.id %>```. In the above comment, you have typed ```<%= employees.id %>``` @dev

Comment: screenshot of db https://ibb.co/DGWC0Mt it was employee I just try to check weather it will work or not so I write employees

Comment: It seems like you are sending the data back to the view in a variable called ```employees```. Maybe you should try to access ```<%= employees.id %>``` instead of ```<%= employee.id %>```.

Comment: still same...……..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198300/discussion-between-dev-and-sasuke-uchiha).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this CRUD + EJS + Mysql + NODE.js
Sample database table included

https://github.com/anuar101/nodejs-crud